# Wake on USB-C keyboard after reconnection

Tags: usb, suspend

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1, but I think this question is generic. I use two separate laptops, and a USB-C adapter two connect a keyboard, mouse and monitor to them. If I suspend (-to-RAM) my laptop, waking it back with the keyboard works correctly. However, switching between laptops requires a more elaborate procedure:

1. Disconnect USB-C adapter from Laptop A
2. Connect USB-C adapter to Laptop B
3. Open lid of Laptop B to wake it (USB keyboard would not wake it up; power button is inaccessible without opening the lid)
4. Close lid of Laptop B

The laptops are normally in a stack, so it's pretty cumbersome. I'd like to just be able to wake Laptop B with the keyboard connected through the USB-C adapter.

(Hardware solution that works but is clunky: Attach second USB-A keyboard to both laptops, use *that* to wake them. I'd prefer a software solution)

My best guess is that something like this is going on:

1. At sleep time, Ubuntu configures the kernel to wake-on-keyboard from keyboards on all *currently connected ports*.
2. Disconnecting the USB-C adapter means that the USB-A "port" which it encapsulates no longer exists
3. Reconnecting the USB-C adapter creates an entirely new USB-A "port" for which wake-on-keyboard is not active.

That's just a guess though. Any ideas on how I can dig deeper into this?

**Update 2022-04-18 - a workaround:**

I ended up using a traditional HDMI+USB-A KVM switch. I use the USB-C adapter with one of the laptops, and the other laptop has HDMI+USB-A, but presumably the workaround would work with two USB-C adapters. Mentioning this because someone asked.

Comment: I think it is more like this: "At sleep time, check if the USB port/controller has any devices on it that could be used to wake the system; if not, fully power down the entire port/controller to save power. If there is a wake-capable device, leave the stand-by power on for this port/controller to allow for sending the wake signal."